# The post rest call returns 201 as response code but location header in response contains NULL

Tags: rest, post

The response code for POST REST call is 201 but the location header in response contains the NULL as ID for newly created row. I don't understand how can this happen. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The 201 status code, may return a location in the header, but when null, you must use the same URI to acces your newly created resource.

Ref : [status code 201](https://httpstatuses.com/201)